# Dart - Adding more than one parameter Type: Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart, payment-gateway, tap

I am trying to integrate Tap payments on my Flutter mobile application.

As per [Tap's documentation](https://www.tap.company/kw/en/developers), I need to pass `src_card` for VISA/MasterCard and `src_kw.knet` for KNET payment gateway. The code below is only accepting one parameter.

```
  Map<String, dynamic> getOrderParams() {
    var cartModel = Provider.of<CartModel>(context, listen: false);
    return {
      'amount': cartModel.getTotal(),
      'currency': kAdvanceConfig.defaultCurrency?.currencyDisplay,
      'threeDSecure': true,
      'save_card': false,
      'receipt': {'email': false, 'sms': true},
      'customer': {
        'first_name': cartModel.address?.firstName ?? '',
        'last_name': cartModel.address?.lastName ?? '',
        'email': cartModel.address?.email ?? '',
      },
      'source': {'id':'src_card'},         <--- HERE
      'post': {'url': kRedirectUrl},
      'redirect': {'url': kRedirectUrl}
    };
  }
```

How can I pass both `src_card` and `src_kw.knet` here? I get this error when I add another param:

> The literal can't be either a map or a set because it contains at
> least one literal map entry or a spread operator spreading a 'Map',
> and at least one element which is neither of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try src_all in place of card

```dart
 'source': {'id':'src_all'},
```

[image: preview]